# 12.04 variable (long) boot times, Lenovo IdeaPad

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, lenovo

I have a Lenovo U430 IdeaPad, 4th gen i7, Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics, Intel 7260 Wireless, Crucial SSD.

It had Win8 when I bought it and I replaced it with Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit, UEFI mode.

When I boot the machine, I get the Lenovo screen (~3 sec), the grub screen (~10 sec timer), then default Ubuntu boot starts.  Sometimes I get the Ubuntu log-on screen right away (~5 sec, after adjusting screen brightness from min to max). Yeah!

Sometimes I get a dark purple, grub-like screen for > 3 minutes and then the Ubuntu log-on screen (after brightness adjustment).  Sometimes I get a black screen with blinking cursor for > 3 minutes and then the Ubuntu log-on screen (after brightness adjustment).

If I get either the dark purple or black screen, and I do a hard reset (power switch), then I get the log-on screen within 5 seconds of grub screen. Yeah!

The same patterns hold for legacy boot configuration.

Three related questions: 
(1) Is there a way to fix this so that I get the normal rapid boot every time?
(2) If not, will I damage my hardware or software if I do a hard reset every time the boot process stalls?
(3) Should I switch to 13.10, or wait until 14.04?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the many ways to solve the problem, here was an approach that worked:

(1) Downloaded latest 13.10, 64-bit Ubuntu, and created a bootable USB flash drive using the "Startup Disk Creator" in Ubuntu.

(2a) Rebooted computer, and accessed the system startup menu (BIOS, hold Fn+F2) at startup.

(2b) Went to the last (Exit) tab and, for the "OS optimal default" option, I chose "other OS".

(2c) Then I chose the "setup defaults" option at the bottom of the screen, and then saved and exited.

(3a) Next, I booted from the new bootable USB flash drive (press Fn+F12 at startup to get this option), and chose the "try Ubuntu" option.

(3b) Once in Ubuntu, I opened "G-Parted" using the dashboard and removed all existing partitions on my Crucial SSD, leaving all space unallocated.

(4a) Next I rebooted from the USB flash drive, as described in 3a, this time choosing to "install Ubuntu".

(4b) I selected the default partitioning, download updates, download restricted software, and virtual file system (or something like this) options and let setup do its thing.

(5) Rebooted and everything works perfectly. Specifically, it boots quickly and reliably, the wireless works without work-arounds, and the screen brighness no longer needs to be manually increased after startup.

Thanks, all, for continually working to improve this outstanding operating system!